# Can't sort data from firebase realtime database by timeStamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am making a challenges between users in my app .I am trying to get the last 15 users who enters in challenges. I store the time each time the users enter a new challenge. The query was working well in the begging but after that it stops showing new users and only old users appears in it.

this is the query code :

```
 usersReference.orderByChild("lastChallengeDate")
            .limitToLast(15)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

and this is the database structre of the user child :

[image]

When I opened the log I found this warn although I am using index on in my rules

> W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "lastChallengeDate"' at users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform a query on a location, Firebase sorts the children under that location on the property you specify. There is no value in `lastChallengeDate` directly under each child of `users`. Instead the property is under `lastChallengeDate/time`, so you should order on that

```
usersReference.orderByChild("lastChallengeDate/time")
        .limitToLast(15)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

You also need to define an index on `users` (or whatever the name is of the node you query):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "lastChallengeDate/time"
    }
  }
}
```

Be sure to also study:

- the [documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data), which includes an example of querying such a nested property
- the [documentation on defining indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes)
- some of the many [questions with the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Using+an+unspecified+index.+Consider+adding+%27%22.indexOn%22)